# How to change all empty rows to NULL?

Tags: php, mysql, null

I have a table like this:

```
// mytable
+----+--------+
| id |  name  |
+----+--------+
| 1  |  Jack  |
| 2  |        |
| 3  |  Peter |
| 4  |        |
| 5  |        |
| 6  |  Alvin |
+----+--------+
```

Also the output of this query is always `1`:

```
SELECT ... (mytable.name IS NOT NULL) as col ... FROM ...

//=> echo result["col"]; -> always it will be "1"
```

Now, how can I change empty records to `NULL`? Because I want it returns `1` just for where there is a name and if there is not any name I want to it returns `0`.

Actually I want something like this:

```
// newtable
+----+--------+
| id |  name  |
+----+--------+
| 1  |  Jack  |
| 2  |  Null  |
| 3  |  Peter |
| 4  |  Null  |
| 5  |  Null  |
| 6  |  Alvin |
+----+--------+
```

How can I convert my table to this ^ ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your table column name is nullable you can update your data:

```
UPDATE mytable
SET name = NULL
WHERE name = '';
```

If your column name is `NOT NULL` you need to alter it first to allow `NULL`.

or if you need to create new table you can use:

```
CREATE TABLE newtable
AS
SELECT id, CASE WHEN TRIM(name) = '' THEN NULL ELSE name END AS name
FROM mytable;
```

Comment: wtf, seems correct, it is much simple. why I couldn't understand it ...! anyway thanks. +1

Comment: May I have your *skype* account?

Comment: @Sajad In SO I communicate through answer/comment/chat only. May I ask why you need it?

Comment: This time is the third time that you have wrote a answer under my question. I liked to have another communicate to you, because sometime I have a few small questions that not valuable for asking in SO ... I wanted to ask them of you ..

Comment: @Sajad Happy to hear I can help. My policy is to help anyone through SO. Don't get me wrong but I won't use another tool for communication. And one more thing every question is valuable for SO, just add context you have, input, desired output and what have you tried. If you have such question you can call me through comment `@lad2025` and if I can I will help.

Comment: Alright :-) ! So I will ping you `@lad2025` if I wanted to know your opinion about my question..! Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

If your table column name is nullable you can update your data and name column should having space

```
UPDATE mytable
SET name = NULL
WHERE replace(name,' ','') = '';
```

Comment: No my column wasn't nullable, but your solution is containing a good point. +1

Comment: For completness you should  use `WHERE TRIM(name) = ''` String can have tab/new line characters and so on. Replace will affect only `'  '`